How can I speed up attribute recovery when using boto3?
I am currently attempting to retrieve the attribute data for all of the buckets within an aws account, the code I have currently works (outside of the environment that each bucket is present in) but it takes a terribly long time to run. I am using a bunch of different retrieval methods because I couldn't quite find one retrievable object containing all of the metadata that I would need. If anyone has ideas of how I can speed things up I would love the help!
import boto3
import csv

import time

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def getTagContents(tagging, keyword):
    storage = list(filter(lambda tag: tag['Key'] == keyword, tagging))
    if storage != "Unknown":
        if len(storage) > 0:
            storage = storage[0]['Value']
    return storage

start_time = time.time()
with open("quicksight-test.csv", "w", newline='') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ["Name", 'CreationDate', 'Versioned', 'Region', 'Product', 'ProductComponent', 'Environment', 'CustomerName', 'CustomerState', 'StorageClass']
    
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    csv_writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    
    response = s3.buckets.limit(50)
    for bucket in response:
        try:
            tagging = s3_client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket = bucket.name)['TagSet']
        except ClientError as e:
            continue
        
        sclass = list(s3.Bucket(bucket.name).objects.limit(1))
        if len(sclass) > 0:
            sclass = sclass[0].storage_class 
        csv_writer.writerow([bucket.name, bucket.creation_date, bucket.Versioning().status,s3_client.get_bucket_location(Bucket = bucket.name)['LocationConstraint'],getTagContents(tagging, "Project"), getTagContents(tagging, "ProductComponent")," ",getTagContents(tagging, "CustomerName"), getTagContents(tagging, "CustomerState"), sclass])
        
end_time = time.time() - start_time

print(end_time)

I have managed to pare down the number of objects I retrieve for each bucket at least, but its still over a second for each bucket.

What is your actual goal? If it's to get an inventory of objects with storage class and other metadata then consider using Amazon S3 Inventory but be aware that it's populated on a daily or weekly basis so is not 'live'.

It was mostly just a primer into boto3 and the aws sdk in general for my internship, I have since moved onto inventories which seem much more useful.
